# Sum the MDX Query

Tags: sum, mdx

I got a MDX Query working which gets me the measure of some countries, on a date range.
But if I set the Date range to more then 1 day, i get every countries value for every day (in the range).
But I want to sum the measures for every country accross the date range.
Thanks in advance. Didnt find a excisting thread ;)

The Query (some parts are crossed-out due to intern data), marked as '???':

```
WITH
SET [*NATIVE_CJ_SET] AS 
   'FILTER(
      NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN(
         [*BASE_MEMBERS__Site.Site Hierarchy_]
        ,NONEMPTYCROSSJOIN(
             [*BASE_MEMBERS__Time.GA Date Hierarchy_]
            ,[*BASE_MEMBERS__Country.Country Hierarchy_]
         )
      )
      , NOT ISEMPTY ([Measures].[???])
    )'
SET [*BASE_MEMBERS__Country.Country Hierarchy_] AS 
  '{
    [Country.Country Hierarchy].[Austria]
   ,[Country.Country Hierarchy].[Germany]
   ,[Country.Country Hierarchy].[India]
   ,[Country.Country Hierarchy].[Switzerland]
   ,[Country.Country Hierarchy].[United States]
   }'
SET [*NATIVE_MEMBERS__Site.Site Hierarchy_] AS 
  'GENERATE(
     [*NATIVE_CJ_SET]
   ,{[Site.Site Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER}
   )'
SET [*SORTED_COL_AXIS] AS 
   'ORDER(
      [*CJ_COL_AXIS]
     ,[Site.Site Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.ORDERKEY,BASC
    )'
SET [*BASE_MEMBERS__Measures_] AS 
   '{[Measures].[???]}'
SET [*BASE_MEMBERS__Site.Site Hierarchy_] AS 
   '{[Site.Site Hierarchy].[???]}'
SET [*BASE_MEMBERS__Time.GA Date Hierarchy_] AS 
   '{
      [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[2016].[8].[1] 
    : [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[2016].[8].[11]
    }'
SET [*CJ_ROW_AXIS] AS 
  'GENERATE(
       [*NATIVE_CJ_SET]
   , {([Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
      ,[Country.Country Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER)}
    )'
SET [*SORTED_ROW_AXIS] AS 
   'ORDER(
      [*CJ_ROW_AXIS]
     ,ANCESTOR(
         [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
       , [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[Year]).ORDERKEY
     ,BASC
     ,ANCESTOR(
         [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
       , [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[Month]).ORDERKEY
     ,BASC
     ,[Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.ORDERKEY
     ,BASC
     ,[Measures].[*SORTED_MEASURE]
     ,BASC)'
SET [*CJ_COL_AXIS] AS 
   'GENERATE(
       [*NATIVE_CJ_SET]
   , {([Site.Site Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER)}
    )'
MEMBER [Measures].[*SORTED_MEASURE] AS '([Measures].[???],[Site.Site Hierarchy].[*TOTAL_MEMBER_SEL~SUM])', SOLVE_ORDER=400
MEMBER [Site.Site Hierarchy].[*TOTAL_MEMBER_SEL~SUM] AS 'SUM([*NATIVE_MEMBERS__Site.Site Hierarchy_])', SOLVE_ORDER=98
SELECT
CROSSJOIN([*SORTED_COL_AXIS],[*BASE_MEMBERS__Measures_]) ON COLUMNS
,[*SORTED_ROW_AXIS] ON ROWS
FROM [???]
```

This is the Output:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/ab236e90880a4d8b969fdd182a05ccdb.png

But I want it like that:
Germany 901
Austria 67

etc.

Comment: I found excisting threads, regarding the sum func. but without the aspect of the date range.

Comment: Try to add a little more context. Show some code and some of a bit of your data if possible.

Comment: http://image.prntscr.com/image/d31fefb0041642328c9f20ee0c0f9343.png this is the result of the query. But I want to have the 5 Countries with the total of numbers. Germany: 851 for example.

Comment: Please supply said MDX Query, output, and expected output. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my orig. post with the new content.

Comment: @TomH. would you be ok reformatting the query (I made a start) so that it is easier for us to read it? MDXStudio (it is free) will do this for you.

Comment: @TomH. the code you have for `[*SORTED_ROW_AXIS]` looks sort of strange, as you seem to have 4 arguments for the order function - is it correct?

Comment: @TomH. the order of the definitions in your WITH clause is dangerous - you need to define things in the order in which they are used - it will still run but can impact performance e.g. [*BASE_MEMBERS__Site.Site Hierarchy_] is used near the start of the WITH but then its definition appears later in the WITH.

Answer (score 0):

I've reformatted your code to try make it a little more readable - this part of your code does not look correct:

```
SET [*SORTED_ROW_AXIS] AS 
   'ORDER(
      [*CJ_ROW_AXIS]
     ,ANCESTOR(
         [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
       , [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[Year]).ORDERKEY
     ,BASC
     ,ANCESTOR(
         [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
       , [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[Month]).ORDERKEY
     ,BASC
     ,[Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.ORDERKEY
     ,BASC
     ,[Measures].[*SORTED_MEASURE]
     ,BASC)'
```

Attempting to simplify your whole script I've got the following - I'll come back to this as it won't solve your problem but I just want to try to understand what is going on:

```
WITH
SET [*NATIVE_CJ_SET] AS 
   NONEMPTY(
         [Site.Site Hierarchy].[???]
       * [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[2016].[8].[1] : [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[2016].[8].[11]
       * {
        [Country.Country Hierarchy].[Austria]
       ,[Country.Country Hierarchy].[Germany]
       ,[Country.Country Hierarchy].[India]
       ,[Country.Country Hierarchy].[Switzerland]
       ,[Country.Country Hierarchy].[United States]
     }
      ,[Measures].[???])
    )
SET [*CJ_COL_AXIS] AS 
   GENERATE(
       [*NATIVE_CJ_SET]
      ,{([Site.Site Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER)}
    )
SET [*NATIVE_MEMBERS__Site.Site Hierarchy_] AS 
   GENERATE(
       [*NATIVE_CJ_SET]
      ,{[Site.Site Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER}
   )
SET [*SORTED_COL_AXIS] AS 
   ORDER(
      [*CJ_COL_AXIS]
     ,[Site.Site Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.ORDERKEY
     ,BASC
   )
SET [*CJ_ROW_AXIS] AS 
   GENERATE(
       [*NATIVE_CJ_SET]
     ,(
       [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
      ,[Country.Country Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
      )
    )
MEMBER [Site.Site Hierarchy].[*TOTAL_MEMBER_SEL~SUM] AS 
    SUM(
      [*NATIVE_MEMBERS__Site.Site Hierarchy_]
    )
  , SOLVE_ORDER=98
MEMBER [Measures].[*SORTED_MEASURE] AS 
    (
      [Measures].[???]
     ,[Site.Site Hierarchy].[*TOTAL_MEMBER_SEL~SUM]
    )
  , SOLVE_ORDER=400
SET [*SORTED_ROW_AXIS] AS 
   ORDER(
      [*CJ_ROW_AXIS]
     ,ANCESTOR(
         [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
       , [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[Year]).ORDERKEY
     ,BASC
     ,ANCESTOR(
         [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER
       , [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[Month]).ORDERKEY
     ,BASC
     ,[Time.GA Date Hierarchy].CURRENTMEMBER.ORDERKEY
     ,BASC
     ,[Measures].[*SORTED_MEASURE]
     ,BASC)
SELECT
   [*SORTED_COL_AXIS] * [Measures].[???] ON 0
  ,[*SORTED_ROW_AXIS] ON 1
FROM [???];
```

Comment: Ok, I usually dont sort by any date. I got my five countries that i want to have the sum for each country over the course of the date range. If I select 2016-01-01 > 2016-08-14 for example. I get eight bars on every country. Eight bars cause to eight months? How can I get rid of that? I just want the sum for every single country.

Comment: @TomH. the thing is I don't understand what is happening in this snippet above - I'm surprised that it does not throw an exception - it does not look like valid mdx to me - did I copy it correctly?

Comment: http://www2.pic-upload.de/img/31464575/Screenshot_2.jpg, this is how my mdx looks like in the pentaho report analyzer. Yeah the MDX should be correct. I got two days as you can see. I just need to know where and how I need to add the SUM? function to get the single values for every country. Germany would have 90 on this picture for example. I´m pretty new to MDX so I cant read the syntax that good.

Comment: @TomH.the script you have posted - was it generated by a client?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
Wrote my own MDX which is much better:

```
SELECT CrossJoin([Site.Site Hierarchy].[???], {[Measures].[???]}) ON COLUMNS,
Order({[Country.Country Hierarchy].[Austria],[Country.Country Hierarchy].[Germany],[Country.Country Hierarchy].[India],[Country.Country Hierarchy].[Switzerland],[Country.Country Hierarchy].[United States]}, Measures.[sessions], BASC) ON ROWS
FROM [???]
WHERE {[Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[2016].[8].[1] : [Time.GA Date Hierarchy].[2016].[8].[17]}
```

But the Order does not work correctly. Whats the Problem?
Result: http://www2.pic-upload.de/img/31482391/Screenshot_1.png